# Why is Selenium not accepting dynamic variables in this function?

Tags: python, html, selenium

Why does this work:

```
monday_div = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GXPMonday"]')
```

but this does not?

```
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

for day in weekdays:
    main_day_div = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GXP' + day + '"]')
```

I get the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="GXPMonday"]
```

This is the website I'm trying to parse: https://movatiathletic.com/clubs/schedule.php?acct=663&loc=2860

**Edit: Thanks for your help everyone, ultimately this was the solution:**

```
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
main_day_div_list = []
all_div_list = []

for day in weekdays:
     main_day_divs = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GXP' + day + '"]')
     main_day_div_list.append(main_day_divs)

for element in main_day_div_list:
    entries = element.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"GXPEntry")
    all_div_list.extend(entries)
```

Comment: In your 2 examples, the top example is using find_element() and the bottom example is using find_elements()

Comment: You should also look into using string format, will make your life easier for passing parameters into a string

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```py
main_day_div = driver.find_element(By.ID,f"GXP{day}")
```

If this doesn't work, you may be running into a timing issue where you would be better served by using `expected_conditions`.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

for day in weekdays:
    main_day_div = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,f"GXP{day}")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is correct, you need to add some wait time, just added the code to print the `GXPTitle` for your reference, check it:

```
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    
for day in weekdays:
    main_day_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GXP' + day + '"]//h6')))
    print("Total titles in -", day ,":", len(main_day_div))
    print("-------")
    for title in main_day_div:
        print(title.text)
    print("=======")
```